# Does Craft have any default keys for flash messages?

Tags: users, user-profile, session, login

Does Craft have any default keys for flash messages like logging in or updating a profile?

Comment: Do you mean for the backend, to display messages in Crafts native alert message format?

Comment: For the frontend, so you can do something like `{% set message = craft.session.getFlash('login') %}` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not particularly.

UserSessionService has [setNotice()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#setNotice-detail) and [setErrors()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/UserSessionService#setError-detail), which are just wrappers for Yii's [setFlash()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#setFlash-detail) where we pass in an `'error'` or `'notice'` for the key.

Yii will take than and prepend the `FLASH_KEY_PREFIX` const which we set to `Craft.UserSessionService.flash.`.

So an error's key will end up being `Craft.UserSessionService.flash.error` and a notice will be `Craft.UserSessionService.flash.notice`.

Comment: So with this I would be able to do something like this `craft.session.getFlash('notice', 'Your settings have been saved')`? Only with the limitation that only one notice can be stored at a time.

Comment: Sounds pretty solid to me.